# What's wrong with my constructor in this moving x matrix?

Tags: java, variables, constructor

The idea is each iteration will move the [x] every time it prints. However it obviously can't print a 0x0 matrix. As you can see I summoned the constructor in the program to have the variables 4, 4. Yet for some reason, after running it, the program still outputs 0,0.

public class MovingX{

```
private int rowsN;

private int columnsM;

private int[][] matrixArr = new int[rowsN][columnsM];

private int x = 0;

private int y = 0;

public MovingX(int n, int m){
   n = rowsN;
    
   m = columnsM;
   
}

public void forLoopGrid(){
            
    for(int i = 0; i < matrixArr.length; i++){
        
        for(int j = 0; j < matrixArr.length; j++){
         
            if(i == x && j == y) System.out.print("[x] ");   
            else System.out.print("[ ] ");

        }
            System.out.println();
    }
        System.out.println();
}

public void moveX(){
     
     if(x < rowsN) x++;
     else{
          x = 0; y++;
     } 
 
}

public void runProgram(){

    System.out.println("Program Starting");
    System.out.println("Rows, Columns: " + rowsN + " " + columnsM);
    for(int i = 0; i < (rowsN * columnsM); i++){
     System.out.println("Stuff happening");
     forLoopGrid();
     moveX();
    }
    System.out.println("Program Ending");

}

public static void main(String[] args){
     
    MovingX xLoop =  new MovingX(4, 4);

    xLoop.runProgram();
    
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be the fact that you are assigning your object's fields(rowsN,columnsM) to the arguments(n,m) supplied to your class constructor.

You see, it doesn't matter what arguments you supply during instantiation when you use those local constructor variables to store the default value of your object's fields. You get (0,0) because all object fields get initialized to a default value and for int, that happens to be 0.

This should work--

```
public MovingX(int n, int m){
       rowsN=n;    //n = rowsN;
        
       columnsM=m;  //m = columnsM;
       
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Reason maybe with the assignment.

```
public MovingX(int n, int m){
   rowsN = n;
    
   columnsM = m;
   
}
```

Try this, they may work.